# How to write a custom function that outputs an image to a Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm working on a Google Drive spreadsheet.

Is it possible to create a custom function / script to display an image?

The idea would be that when I typed the function (= tick) a tick mark image would be displayed in the cell.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert Unicode characters into the cell of a Google spreadsheet:

> =CHAR( HEX2DEC( "2713" ))

That inserts a check mark into the cell.

One option would be to use an `onEdit()` simple trigger to check for what was entered into the current cell:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log("onEdit ran" + e);
  var input = e.value;

  if (input === "inputTick") {
    var whatCell = e.range;
    //Run a function named insertTick and pass the range
    insertTick(whatCell);
  }; 
};
```

In the above example, the user would need to enter "inputTick" into the cell.

There *is* a function to insert an image into a cell:

[Google Documentation =IMAGE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333)

One possible syntax:

> IMAGE(url, mode)

You can set (insert) a formula into a cell with code:

```
var cell = sheet.getRange("B5");
cell.setFormula("=IMAGE(url, mode)");
```

Here is a function that gets the passed cell location, and inserts a function
with a Unicode character of a check mark.

```
function insertTick(argWhatCell) {
  Logger.log(argWhatCell);
  //Insert a formula into a cell that converts HEX to a Character
  argWhatCell.setFormula("=CHAR( HEX2DEC( "2713" ))");
}
```

The above code inserts a function, that then converts a Unicode to a check mark.

If you wanted to insert an image that can't be displayed with a Unicode, this function might work:

```
function insertTick(argWhatCell) {
  Logger.log(argWhatCell);
  var rngValues = argWhatCell.getValue();

  Logger.log(rngValues);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //Get row and column
  var row = argWhatCell.getRow();
  var column = argWhatCell.getColumn();

  Logger.log(row + " : " + column);

  //Insert an image by URL
  ss.insertImage(url, column, row)
}
```

The above code, using `insertImage()` inserts an image at the position of the cell, but the image isn't inside of the cell.